# Batch modifying file metadata

Tags: terminal, software-recommendation, file, metadata, time

I'm looking for an application or command line tool that can batch edit file metadata. I have some audio files recorded using a recorder that was off by 1 hour, and I want to **modify the creation date** to the correct time.

Comment: This has command line, but I'm not sure how you'd batch "-1 hour" - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99536/changing-creation-date-of-a-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use "touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm" followed by your file name/path, of course replacing YYYYMMDDhhmm with your desired date.  I recommend typing "man touch" into terminal to look at the manual and different command options there.